# Issue with adding num to calculator

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a calculator small project and I'm having some issues I can't not solve.

When I execute the first operation (i.e: 9 x 3) it will work fine, pressing 9 will store that number on `currentNum` and then pressing an operator will store the actual number on `prevNum` and will show it on `displayPrevResult` text content along with the operator, pressing another number will replace `currentNum` with the new number and then pressing equal will calculate the result of `currentNum` and `prevNum`, store it on `result` variable and show it on `displayCurrentResult` textContent while `displayPrevResult` text content will show the last operation (9 x 3 =).

So far it works fine with the first operation but pressing another operation and adding more numbers doesn't work as I intend to, it will replace the value of `currentNum` but it won't replace the operation (9 x 3 =) of `displayPrevResult` text content, instead, the numbers keeps adding to it.

I want the operation and the `displayCurrentResult` text content to keep changing everytime I execute and operation, i.e:

9 x 3 will show "9 x 3 =" on the `displayPrevResult` text content, then `displayCurrentResult` will show 18, pressing "+" and a 5 will replace the content of `displayCurrentResult` to "18" (last result) and replace the text content of `displayPrevResult` to 27 and keep operating, adding +5 to the result and displaying it, and so on...

Just right like this calculator: https://michalosman.github.io/calculator/

I haven't read the code because I'm trying to improve my logic.

```js
const displayPrevResult = document.querySelector('.prev-result');
const displayCurrentResult = document.querySelector('.current-result');
const equal = document.querySelector('.equal');
const decimal = document.querySelector('.decimal');
const clear = document.querySelector('.clear');

const numberBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
const operatorBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.operator');

let prevNum = '';
let secondNum = '';
let currentNum = '';
let result = '';
let operator = '';

equal.addEventListener('click', calculate);
// decimal.addEventListener('click', addDecimal)
clear.addEventListener('click', clearCalc);

numberBtn.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        getNumber(e.target.textContent);
    })
})

operatorBtn.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        getOperator(e.target.textContent);
    })
})

function calculate() {

    prevNum = Number(prevNum);
    currentNum = Number(currentNum);

    if (operator === '+') {
        result = prevNum + currentNum;
        displayCurrentResult.textContent = result;
    } if (operator === '-') {
        result = prevNum - currentNum;
        displayCurrentResult.textContent = result;
    } if (operator === 'x') {
        result = prevNum * currentNum;
        displayCurrentResult.textContent = result;
    } if (operator === '÷') {
        result = prevNum / currentNum;
        displayCurrentResult.textContent = result;
    }

    currentNum = currentNum.toString();
    prevNum = prevNum.toString();
    secondNum = currentNum;
    displayPrevResult.textContent += ' ' + secondNum + ' =';
    currentNum = '';
}

function getNumber(num) {
    currentNum += num;
    displayCurrentResult.textContent = currentNum;
}

function getOperator(op) {
    if (operator === '') {
        operator = op;
        prevNum += currentNum;
        displayPrevResult.textContent = currentNum + ' ' + ' ' + operator;
        currentNum = '';

        if (currentNum == '') {
            displayPrevResult.textContent += result;
        }
    }
}

function clearCalc() {
    prevNum = '';
    secondNum = '';
    currentNum = '';
    result = '';
    operator = '';

    displayPrevResult.textContent = '';
    displayCurrentResult.textContent = '0';
}
```

```css
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.calcContainer {
    background: linear-gradient(276deg, #40a179, #77cea9);
    padding: 1em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

button {
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0.1em;
    width: 40px;
    background: #a2ffaf;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
    background: #72e782;
}

.clr {
    background: #87e4bd;
}

.clr:hover {
    background: #53ad88;
}

.clear {
    margin: 0em 0.1em 0.5em 0.5em;
    padding: 0;
}

.output-clear-container {
    display: flex;
}

.output {
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 40px;
    background: #c2fcca;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.par {
    margin-bottom: 0.3em;
}

.prev-result {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 0.3em;
    color:#40a179;
}

.current-result {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="main.js" defer></script>
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="calcContainer">
        <div class="output-clear-container">
            <div class="output">
                <div class="prev-result"></div>
                <div class="current-result">0</div>
            </div>
            <button class="clear">AC</button>
        </div>
            <div class="par">
                <button class="number">7</button>
                <button class="number">8</button>
                <button class="number">9</button>
                <button class="operator clr">÷</button>
            </div>
            <div class="par">
                <button class="number">4</button>
                <button class="number">5</button>
                <button class="number">6</button>
                <button class="operator clr">x</button>
            </div>
            <div class="par">
                <button class="number">1</button>
                <button class="number">2</button>
                <button class="number">3</button>
                <button class="operator clr">-</button>
            </div>
            <div class="par">
                <button class="decimal clr">.</button>
                <button class="number">0</button>
                <button class="equal clr">=</button>
                <button class="operator clr">+</button>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Did you try debugging?  Where do things go wrong?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the console.log() to see where I'm failing, so far I have concluded that I'm maybe reassigning different results on the variables on each function, I'm not familiarized with Chrome / FF dev tools yet (using breakpoints) so I'm debugging with pen and paper but I am stucked at the moment, maybe programming logic is not for me because I got stucked often.

Comment: I think you haven't worked out the state machine for your calculator yet.  Two interesting cases that are different with your code from the example.  `9x3+` and `9x3=+`  Your `+` key isn't doing the right thing in either of these cases.  Also, both of your calculators display differently from Windows Calc for just `9=`, although the example continues to perform adequately in spite of not displaying "9 =".

Comment: Right, I have a problem with the arbitrary use of the `+=` when I should not, it drives me crazy sometimes, otherwise you are right, I have solved my problem but I also need to set the state machine properly before setting up my calculator, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say, but I think your problem is in this function.
First of all your operator isn't clear every time and this condition doesn't work
And second you override your `displayPrev`. As I understand it, you want to keep the whole history?

```
function getOperator(op) {
if (operator === '') {
    operator = op;
    prevNum += currentNum;
    // should use += instead = ?
    displayPrevResult.textContent = currentNum + ' ' + ' ' + operator;
    currentNum = '';
    // operator = '' clear?
    if (currentNum == '') {
        displayPrevResult.textContent += result;
    }
}
```

}

Upd.

Variables in the end of calculate

```
currentNum = currentNum.toString();
prevNum = prevNum.toString();

secondNum = currentNum;
displayPrevResult.textContent += ' ' + secondNum + ' =';

currentNum = result;
prevNum = '';
operator = '';
```

And getOperator function

```
function getOperator(op) {
if (operator === '') {
    operator = op;
    prevNum += currentNum;
    displayPrevResult.textContent = currentNum + ' ' + ' ' + operator;
    currentNum = '';
    // if (currentNum == '') {
    //     displayPrevResult.textContent += result;
    // }
}
```

}

Comment: Yeah clearing the `operator` won't make much difference, I wan't to override the last `displayPrevResult` text content with new result, like:

9 + 2 = 11 (displayPrevResult shows "9 + 2 =" (the last number you press) and displayCurrentResult will show 11 which is the result), then clicking i.e "+" will replace "9 + 2 =" with "11 +", clicking 8 will now show on displayPrevResult "11 + 8 =" and displayCurrentResult 19 and so on

Comment: Are you using the result in further calculations? I didn't find.

Please check update above, but I didn't handle with all history.
I hope it's help a little

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, you are correct, clearing the variables helped me a lot, I also added this: `else if (displayPrevResult.textContent !== '') {
        displayPrevResult.textContent += result;
    }`
on the `getOperator` function and now seems to work as I intended.

Comment: Nice! Good luck :)